# Debugging foldexpr function

Tags: vimrc, folding, debugging

I have `debug=msg,throw` in my .vimrc.

When trying to debug a foldexpr function, the `echom` statements I use to print are ignored and are not accessible by `:messages`. Any way to make them work?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have a clear answer to your problem, but a few tricks that you could use instead. Typically, you could add the messages into a `|List|` and display them (the list) on demand.

In my (complex) [folding plugin for C&C++](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C), I've used various techniques:

- balloons to display various information when the mouse is over a line
- signs to display in front of each line what the related call to foldexpr has returned
- [my logging framework](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md) that can report messages to the quickfix window (which is quite slow and best to not overuse each time `foldexpr` is evaluated)

Unfortunately, when there is an error, the only thing that permits to see the error is something like

```
:echo map(range(1, line('$')), 'the_fold_function(v:val)')
```

This last trick should also permit to display the messages you have produced.